# Webform Contributions Error Since Last Update

Tags: webform-civicrm, stripe

Running Civi 5.28.0, I have recently upgraded Stripe Extension :

- STRIPE PAYMENT PROCESSOR to 6.5.1
- MJWSHARED to 0.9.4

Since then, payments via webforms fail in unexpected Error.

How can I retreive a working configuration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [contribution transaction api](https://civicrm.org/extensions/contribution-transact-api) extension...

Comment: Thank you Pradeep  ; I didn't know.